# IConfiguration returning null. Cannot Read from Database

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .Net Core 3.1 Program returning the error

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')'

when I try to login to the system.

I have set a breakpoint onto

`public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }`

On building,the connection string can be seen but immediately I login it returns null.

Below is my code.

Startup.cs

```cs
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Login/Login", "");
    });

    services.AddDbContext<CENTREContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));
    //var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings");
    //services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseConnection"));

    //services.AddDbContext<CENTREContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
}
```

ContextClass

```cs
public CENTREContext(DbContextOptions<CENTREContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}

public CENTREContext()
{ }

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {               
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.
        GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnection"));
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```json
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DatabaseConnection": "Server=xx-xx;Database=CENTRE;UID=xx;Password=xxx;"
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I have tried but nothing seems to work.
Help on the same will be appreciated.

Comment: You're using `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")` in one place but `Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnection")` in another - they can't both be correct.

Comment: @MartinCostello I had tried this before and the error is still the same

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed your options.

#### GetSection + index operator

```cs
connectionStrings = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings");
connectionString = connectionStrings["DatabaseConnection"];
```

#### GetSection + path

```cs
connectionString = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnection").Value;
```

#### GetConnectionString

```cs
connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection");
```

---

[image]

Comment: What is the best approach

Comment: @Nickson The last one is just a [wrapper](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/master/src/Config.Abstractions/ConfigurationExtensions.cs#L34) around the first one. In my opinion the 3rd one is most concise and convenient.

Comment: No, I changed all connection strings to match the 3rd option but the error is still the same

Comment: @Nickson Did you mean the connectionstrings retrieval logic?

Comment: Yes, it seems like the connection string isn't being passed and hence returned as null

Comment: @Nickson have you tried to examine what does this call return: `configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")`?

Comment: A breakpoint on the startup.cs section returns the JsonconfigurationProvider for the appsettings.json wth the key as `ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnection` and value as the whle connectionstring to the database

Comment: @Nickson So do I understand correctly that the appsettings.json has been parsed successfully by asp.net core but none of the above mentioned methods returns the actual connectionstring?

Comment: Exactly. None of the methods return the actual connectionstring

Comment: @Nickson Based on the provided information I've tried to recreate the problem. For me  all of the above three methods returned the connectionstring. (I've amended my post to include a picture about it)

Comment: I also have a connectionstring returned when I breakpoint, but I think this issue goes way beyond that. I think I messed up somewhere. However I would like to thank you for your tremendous effort and assist.